# Fit webpage to screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a standard way to make my page take up the entire screen without having any scroll bars?  It's changing depending on what monitor I'm using so I would like to standardize it.  My only idea would be to make all of the elements styled with percentages, but I was hoping there would be a property like `screen.height` or something.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If there was, you'd probably see it everywhere instead of the standard 960px layout.

Comment: Screen sizes if including mobile screens can range from 160px to 1200px+ desktop screens.  You would have to have almost no content on your page to never ever have scrollbars unless you want to hide content via `overflow:hidden`

Comment: You might be also interested in responsive web design (some examples for that here: http://mediaqueri.es/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many, many ways ... my personal favorite is a giant wrapper that you put everything inside of with the following CSS:

```
#WrapAll {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This is valid all the way back to IE7 (and I think before that, but untested), and guaranteed to render the same on any standards-based browser.

If you need things to scroll, you can set the overflow values for the items inside. It scrolls within the window, without the entire window scrolling.

If you don't want to do `position:absolute;` (some people are uncomfortable with it), you can accomplish similar things with:

```
#WrapAll {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This may seem shorter, but it also is less guaranteed because of the way browsers render margins, borders, etc. Either way will work in most scenarios though.

Comment: Why use the wrapper in this case and not just the body? body: overflow:hidden.
Of course you'd also need to remove any padding/margins from html and body.

Comment: well for one, with wrapper with position absolute your body would have a height of 0, so you would need to reapply the same CSS to your body, defeating the wrapper. but even beyond that, what would be the gain of applying it to the body? since the wrapper is acting as your body, there is no discernable difference, so by segregating CSS assignments you're only creating extra work and confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would use css if I were you, but jQuery does let you get those values...

```
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

[jQuery Doc on width](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS would probably be best for this.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.fixedOverlay {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

</head>
<body>
<div class="fixedOverlay">
 hello world
</div>
</body>
</html>
```